# Node express http2 no cookie in response

Tags: node.js, express, http2

I have a functional app working with node express using node 18.17.1

I added http2-express-bridge to my app and when I try to access it, the app starts looping with my login process (the response I got from microsoft does not have the cookie session set)

I have tried using:

```
const requestOptions = {
    withCredentials: true
};

...

clientOAuth2.getToken(uri, requestOptions).then(
 token => {
...
```

But the cookie is not being sent within the response header.

[image: Response from microsoft login]

Could someone tell me what am I missing?